# Conditionally add attribute directive to the ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to know if its possible to add attribute directive to some elements inside of ng-repeat. I have tried checking CSS class or id but without luck.

Example code

```
class ItemNavigation {

  constructor(NavigationService ) {
      this.NavigationService = NavigationService;
  }

}

angular.module('core')
  .directive('itemNavigation', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      bindToController: true,
      scope: {
        itemId: '='
      },
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        $timeout(() =>{
          elem.bind('click', function() {
            let noRedirect = $(this).hasClass('no-redirect');
            // this approch doesnt work it never finds class
            if(!noRedirect) return ctrl.NavigationService.goToItemDetails(ctrl.itemId)        
          })
        })
       ;
      },
      controller: ItemNavigation 
    };
  });
```

Example of html

```
    <tr ng-repeat="item in $data track by item.id" item-navigation item-id="item.id">
      <td class="no-redirect">I dont want my directive to work here</td>
      <td>I want my directive to work here</td>
      <td>I want my directive to work here</td>
      <td class="no-redirect">I dont want my directive to work here</td>
      <td>I want my directive to work here</td>
      <td>I want my directive to work here</td>
    </tr>
```

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add event target to your code it also will solve issues if you need to copy text from tds and your directive will work only when you click outside of text. Also you can remove timeout from your code.

Please check following changes

```
   <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="one in data" row-navigation item-id="one.id"
      class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <td class="no-redirect">Dont alert when i click here</td>
        <td><span class="no-redirect">Dont when i click on this text only, but works in TD element</span></td>
        <td>Alert when i click here</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

and your linking function should look like this

```
 app.directive('rowNavigation', function () {
    return {
      scope: {
        itemId: '='
      },
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

          elem.bind('click', function(event) {
            var noRedirect = $(event.target).hasClass('no-redirect');
            // it will work now
            if(!noRedirect) alert(ctrl.itemId)        
          })

      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        this.itemId = $scope.itemId
       } 
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

I think you can; As per my understanding, you want to put a condition for even rows only.

One easy solution: Put a condition using $index inside ng-repeat rows.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="item in $data track by item.id" item-navigation item-id="item.id">
  <td class="no-redirect" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">I dont want my directive to work here</td>
  <td class="no-redirect" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0">I want my directive to work here</td>

</tr>
```

These are the changes you need to make in your directive.

```
   app.directive('rowNavigation', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      scope: {
    itemId: '='
  },
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      $timeout(function() {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
         console.log(ctrl)
         alert(ctrl.itemId);
      })
   });
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
    this.itemId = $scope.itemId
   } 
};
});
```

And in you ng-repeat, change it to

```
 <tr ng-repeat="one in data"  item-id="one.id"
  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <td  class="no-redirect">Dont alert when i click here</td>
    <td row-navigation item-id="one.id">Alert when i click here</td>
    <td row-navigation item-id="one.id">Alert when i click here</td>
  </tr>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my template was just an example currently I have 16tds and their number may change they may switch positions against each other as well hence i need a better way of applying  item-navigation to <tds> which meet condition.

Comment: So instead of checking on number, have your condition in ng-if. I guess you must be having some flag which can help you to define a condition

Comment: Honestly i don't have any flag coming from backend setting one myself would be pretty much equal of adding directive manually to every td where I need it instead of tr.

Comment: If you do not have any flag, then how will you identify, where you want to add directive and where you don't want to ?

Comment: That's where from idea with css class or id came from

Comment: Did you tried changing it from this to elem and how are you putting the class no-redirect ?  I mean, how do you decide it if you dont have any condition?

Comment: I'm allowed to add css classes to tds myself. I have tried to with  elem.hasClass('no-redirect') no luck it always returns false even if click on td which has that class.
I think its because elem returns me all tds inside tr (currently childElementCount 11) instead of the actually td i click on...

Comment: It will be great if you can put the sample code in jsfiddle. I can probably look into it and help you better.

Comment: Thank you alot for your time Rahul I made a simple sample here

http://plnkr.co/edit/sW9UOYBayPDupMNHKwcx?p=info

Please keep in mind i can't really use Event.stopPropagation()  either(i know it would make my life much easier)

Comment: @ArthurStepanyuk  Check the changes in my answer now.

Comment: Yes this would work, still lots of code duplication guess it cant really be helped and save me lots of troubles with handling events on mobile aswell. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be binding it to the window object when checking for `hasClass` instead of the `element` itself.

```
let noRedirect = $(this).hasClass('no-redirect'); // update this
let noRedirect = elem.hasClass('no-redirect'); // this should help
```

Can you `console.log` it to verify ?
let us know.

Comment: Context is same 

I have tryed to use  noRedirect = elem.hasClass('no-redirect'); approch before too

    console.log($(this))
    console.log(elem)

return same object that has a template as 0 element which has all the elements inside of tr so all my tds inside the childNodes

Comment: Hmm..based on your comment.. if you are looking to make the cell `td` clickable shouldn't the attribute be on the `td` instead of `tr`? Or are you checking if any one of the td inside the tr has that class ?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to find if td i click on has a css class

Lets say I have 16 tds. i need redirect to work only on 14 of those

Comment: Ku. so use the attribute `item-navigation` on the `td` instead of the `tr`, so the element you bind is the individual td instead of the entire row. Plus you will have the element's `class` available to you and the check you implemented should work.

Comment: If I use this approach id have to add item-navigation to 14 tds right now id really like to avoid this solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to change click behavior on child nodes, just use the `ng-click` directive:

```
<table>
<!--       Also please dont use stop Event.stopPropagation() 
           as it breaks some of flow on mobile devices in my application 
-->
  <tr ng-repeat="one in data" ng-click="alert(one.id)"
  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <td class="no-redirect" ng-click="dontAlert($event)">
        Dont alert when i click here</td>
    <td>Alert when i click here</td>
    <td>Alert when i click here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And to avoid using `event.stopPropagation`, have the child click handler set a flag for the parent click handler:

```
var dontAlertFlag = false;

$scope.alert = function(id) {
    !dontAlertFlag && alert(id);
    dontAlertFlag = false;
};
$scope.dontAlert = function(event) {
    //event.stopPropagation();
    dontAlertFlag = true;
    console.log(event);
}
```

In the above example, when the child element is clicked, the child click handler sets the `dontAlertFlag` to `true`. The parent click handler uses the flag and then resets it.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/etiwNyt8aHqynelV1wS9?p=preview)

---

### Update

The code can be simpified by using the `event.target` property:

```
<table>
<!--       Also please dont use stop Event.stopPropagation() 
           as it breaks some of flow on mobile devices in my application 
-->
  <tr ng-repeat="one in data" ng-click="alert(one.id,$event)"
  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <td class="no-redirect">
        Dont alert when i click here</td>
    <td>Alert when i click here</td>
    <td>Alert when i click here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
   $scope.alert = function(id,event) {
        var $target = angular.element(event.target);
        console.log($target);
        if (!$target.hasClass("no-redirect")) {
             alert(id);
        }
        console.log(event);
    };
```

In the above example, the click handler checks the target to see if it has a class called `no-redirect`. If the target doesn't have that class, it fires the alert.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/uCeY6ElIvhpbNISZcq2C?p=preview)